# How quickly can an element be doubleclicked multiple times?

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events

If an element is clicked twice, the 'dblclick' event is fired. If the element continues to be clicked, the 'dblclick' event does not continue to be fired. The 'dblclick' event will only be fired once until a "cooloff" period is complete, eg. there is a time to wait before another 'dblclick' event can be fired no matter how many times the element is clicked.

I cannot find any documentation that specifies how long must elapse before another 'dblclick' can occur. Does anyone know what the 'dblclick' "cooloff" period is?

I have tried to test this by scripting the clicking of an element, but for some reason javascript-invoked clicks do not trigger 'dblclick' events. So I have tested manually and I can't get a double-click to occurred any sooner than ~400ms after another double-click has occurred. You can try yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/5v4pcx2k/8/

```
code
```

If you're wondering, this is basically what it seems like the browser is doing https://jsfiddle.net/b0y5ej2y/3/

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few bugs and inefficiencies in your jsfiddle.

- h1 element has no end tag (you think your ending it with /hi)
- you don't need jquery
- the general advice around the webs, seem to be don't mix click and dblclick event listeners on the same element
- the event already has a property on it that tells you when it fired, you don't need to ask for the current time again with Date.now()

Having said all that, I still couldn't manually click any faster than about ~700ms. I think what's happening is it's the window manager / OS / mouse driver is artificially holding back double clicks to some speed limit.

Here's my version of a jsfiddle test for dblclick speed, with a working programatic dblclick simulation which can dblclick as fast as every 4ms on my computer.

https://jsfiddle.net/stephencarmody/v0b3dpwc/

```
var lastOne;

foobar.addEventListener('dblclick', function (event) {
    log.innerText = 'elapsed: ' + (event.timeStamp  - lastOne);
    lastOne = event.timeStamp;
});

function simulateClick () {
    var event = new MouseEvent('dblclick', {
        'view': window,
        'bubbles': true,
        'cancelable': true
    });
    foobar.dispatchEvent(event);
}

setInterval(simulateClick, 0);
```

Comment out the setInterval line to test manual dblclick events.

Comment: Yeah, but you're generating the event manually. Something is rate-limiting the event when it's done by the user, and I would like to know what that rate-limit is.

Comment: Also, it's a jsfiddle, I'm just writing something up as quickly as possible to get my point across so that I get this question up. Thanks but no thanks for your critique. It comes off as poorly